# fadeIn and out DIV2 on hover of DIV1 with unique ID

Tags: jquery, css

I have a bunch of div's with a unique id and I want them to show a transparent effect when hovered.

how can i make this work properly with unique ids and no blinking?

Here is what I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/mKDP4/

```
<img src="test.jpg" class="ad_cover" id="1">
<div class="ad_fade" id="fade1"></div>
```

jquery

```
$('.ad_cover').mouseover(function() {
    var ad_id = this.id;
    $('#fade'+ad_id).fadeIn('slow');
});
$('.ad_cover').mouseout(function() {
    var ad_id = this.id;
    $('#fade'+ad_id).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: to make this work properly without blinking and actually work with unique ids

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using simple css depends on what are your target browsers

http://jsfiddle.net/89pBb/

```
 <a href="#"><div id="test">bla bla bla</div></a>

 a #test{padding:20px; background-color:#F00; width:200px; height:200px;}
 a:hover #test{opacity:0.5; transition: opacity .2s ease-out; -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-out; -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-out; -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;}
```

Comment: i want to be able to add info into the new div that appears and this won't do that

Comment: I'm sorry but can you please explain are you looking for a fade hover effect or something more?

Comment: I want to hover ad_cover, and have ad_fade fadeIn. But since I have a bunch of divs with the class ad_fade, i want to dynamically fadeIn for the specific unique div that is hovered

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $('.ad_cover').mouseenter(function() {
      var ad_id = this.id;
      $('#fade'+ad_id).stop().fadeIn();
  });
  $('.ad_cover').mouseleave(function() {
      var ad_id = this.id;
      $('#fade'+ad_id).stop().fadeOut();
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maysamsh/mKDP4/3/